# console.log not working within jquery ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I'm using Chrome's developer tools and for some reason SOME of my console.log code isn't working. I have code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("wtf"); //this shows in the console
  $.ajax({
    url: 'get_data.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data); //this does not show in the console.
    }
  });
});
```

I know that data is being sent from my PHP file because I can see it in my network tab.

Console.log is also working fine with other code that I have. What's going on here?

EDIT:

Apparently, it's not getting into my `success` function because of an issue with the data. I changed around my PHP code and was able to get console.log to show the right data.

So, why is `success` handler not working? Here's the relevant part of my PHP:

```
$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json= json_encode($result);
$someArray = json_decode($json, true);
  foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["category"] . ", ";
  }
```

Comment: what is your php file returning?

Comment: Clearly, I'm not doing something right. My PHP ends up returning a string of values that are comma separated. I'm sure I'm not calling the data correctly.

Comment: Well for starters you're telling JS you are expecting JSON in return and you are not returning JSON in PHP

Comment: Try `dataType: "text" `

Comment: Please try adding "error" function to your ajax call and check if your control is going to error or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your PHP data rather than echo it.

So something like this:

```
$json = json_encode($result);
return $json;
```

This will return your $json array back into your Ajax call and you will be able to manipulate the data there. You will also then see the console log display correctly.